# Particular determinant made of powers of algebraic numbers is nonzero?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $P$ be a degree-two polynomial, with roots $\alpha,\beta$. Is there a simple condition on $P$ (or on $\alpha,\beta$), equivalent to the following :

$$
(*)\alpha^i\beta^j-\alpha^j\beta^i+\beta^i-\beta^j+\alpha^j-\alpha^i=
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha^i-1 &\beta^i-1 \\
\alpha^j-1 & \beta^j-1 
\end{array}\right|
\neq 0, \ \text{for any } i,j\in{\mathbb Z}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace,i \neq j.
$$

If the coefficients of $P$ are integers, is (*) a decidable question ?

Motivation : (*) is equivalent to the fact that any linear recurrence sequence of the form $c_1\alpha^i+c_2\beta^i$ does not attain any value more than twice, unless it is zero.